what are the consequences of re-encoding with 0 or -1?
I have a dataset of information about students and the last column is the target variable which is the final note. My goal is to make logistic regression and ordinal regression models to see whether for a given student, they will either pass or not.
There are enough missing values so that simply deleting them is not possible and it is not wanted anyways (because for example a missing value for quiz #5 result means that the student did not take it at all and that is an information that I want to preserve)(best note is 1 and worst is 5, so there are no 0s for the results) so I want to give it a value that means that this student did not take that quiz.
I thought of either 0 or -1 but I am not sure about the consequences it has on the logistic/ordinal reg. model (for the coefficients when they are multiplied with the value or something along those lines.)

Will this information enter the model as a continuous or categorical predictor? If the former you end up with missing being the same effect as going from second best to best mark (coded as 0) or twice that (coded as -1). Either way the direction is wrong if you don't want to consider missing as the best outcome. If categorical it really doesn't matter as it'll be its own parameter, for interpretability you might consider what'll become the (default) reference.

Have you considered multiple imputation?

@PeterFlom, I cannot do the multiple imputation because missing data means no test has been taken and I want somewhat keep that information as it is with my encoding. The possible result go from 5 to 1 (continuous values) but NA means that no test has been taken and from what I know if I encode that as 0 I may lose the effect of that variable and if I encode itas -1 it will have a negative effect. So what is the best way to go about it ?
